# Sending events through bluetooth in android

Tags: android, events, bluetooth

I have created a bluetooth connection between two phones(the paired device don't have my app). How to send events to the phone like screen lock/ volume up

`BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
            handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(connectionCheckTimeout,30000);
            BluetoothReciever bluetoothReciever = new BluetoothReciever();
            bluetoothReciever.registerBluetoothRecieverForConnection(this,this);
            SocketThread socketThread = SocketThread.getInstance();
            socketThread.registerBluetoothRecieverForCommunication(this,this);
            Thread thread = new Thread(socketThread);
            thread.start();
        }`

my socket thread class is here, i am getting a connected device(not just paired). 
Now i have to send events like volume up/down to the other device which doesn't run my app.

```
public class SocketThread implements Runnable {
private static SocketThread ourInstance = new SocketThread();
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
BluetoothDevice device;
BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
static BluetoothSocketListener bluetoothSocketListener;
public static SocketThread getInstance() {
    return ourInstance;
}

private SocketThread() {
}

@Override
public void run() {

    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    device = connectedDevice(bluetoothAdapter);
    if (device!=null){
       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"connected to "+device.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (bluetoothSocketListener!=null) {
            bluetoothSocketListener.deviceIsConnected(device,bluetoothSocket);
        }

        try {
            bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream().flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
        if (bluetoothSocketListener!=null) {
            bluetoothSocketListener.deviceIsNotConnected();
        }
    }

}

private BluetoothDevice connectedDevice(BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter){
    if (bluetoothAdapter == null)
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices().size() == 0)
        return null;
    //now create socket to all paired devices. Check if connected. then return true
    Set<BluetoothDevice> btDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    for (BluetoothDevice device : btDevices){
        Log.d("main activity"," trying to create socket for paired device "+device.getName());
        try {
            bluetoothSocket
                    = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(device.getUuids()[0].getUuid());
            bluetoothSocket.connect();
            if (bluetoothSocket.isConnected()){
                return device;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public void registerBluetoothRecieverForCommunication(Context context, BluetoothSocketListener bluetoothSocketListener){
    this.bluetoothSocketListener = bluetoothSocketListener;
}
```

}

Comment: what you have done so far? please share your codes

Comment: Sachith, please find the updated code

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth sends raw data. Apparently, you have to parse those somehow and transform into calls in your app, doing some work

Comment: Here, i have to send raw data like volume up/down events. How to do that?